# failed to run two threads using #[tokio::main] macro

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am trying to understand how `tokio` runtime works, i created two runtimes(on purpose) using `#[tokio::main]` macro, the first should executes `function a()` and the second executes `function b()`.

I am assuming that they should be both printing `"im awake A"` and `"im awake B"` simultaniosuly forever (since they are calling a function that has a loop `async_task`), however that is not the case, it only prints `"im awake A".`

since each runtime has its own thread pool; why they are not running in parallel?

```
use std::thread;
fn main() {
    a();
    b();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn a() {
    tokio::spawn(async move { async_task("A".to_string()).await });
}

pub async fn async_task(msg: String) {
    loop {
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!("im awake {}", msg);
    }
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn b() {
    tokio::spawn(async move { async_task("B".to_string()).await });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `a();` from the synchronous `main` function will block until `a()` finishes. Check out the documentation here: https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/attr.main.html

> ```rust
> #[tokio::main] 
> async fn main() {
>     println!("Hello world"); 
> }
> ```
>
> Equivalent code not using #[tokio::main]
>
> ```rust
>   fn main() {
>     tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
>         .enable_all()
>         .build()
>         .unwrap()
>         .block_on(async {
>             println!("Hello world");
>         }) }
> ```

To get your example to work, `main()` could also spawn 2 threads that run a, b and wait for them to finish:

```rust
fn main() {
    let t1 = thread::spawn(|| {
        a();
    });
    let t2 = thread::spawn(|| {
        b();
    });

    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();
}
```

EDIT:
**Note that `a()` and `b()` also do not need to use `tokio::spawn` as they're already executing in their own async runtime.**

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn a() -> Result<(), JoinError> {
    async_task("A".to_string()).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn b() {
   async_task("B".to_string()).await
}
```

If you use `tokio::spawn` in `a` and `b`, you would need to await the spawned future, but `tokio::spawn(task.await).await` is basically the same as just doing `task.await`.

Comment: to use multiple runtimes @Jmb

Comment: Your `main` function doesn't need to be `async` nor to be annotated with `tokio::main` since all it does is spawn threads and wait for them ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f52a126456b28bd619cb086c4aee796e)).

Comment: This is true if you remove the `tokio::spawn` from `a` and `b`, e.g. 
```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn a() {
    async_task("A".to_string()).await;
}
```. As written, without main also being async, there is a race condition where in some cases only A, only B, both, or nothing will be returned by the time main finishes.

Comment: @TylerAldrich I don't see what `main` being async changes since `main`, `a` and `b` all use different runtimes, so if there is such a race condition, then having `main` async in another runtime won't fix it.

Comment: @Jmb you're totally right, I failed to notice both versions have the same race condition (for whatever reason the async version happened less frequently, but existed regardless) because the `tokio::spawn()` in `a()` and `b()` was never awaited, so occasionally the program could exit or `join` the thread before the tokio task was spawned. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`#[tokio::main]` expands to a call to [`Runtime::block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on), and as said in its docs (emphasis mine):

> This runs the given future on the current thread, **blocking until it is complete**, and yielding its resolved result.

If you use [`Runtime::spawn()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.spawn) instead (and make sure not to drop the runtime because it shuts it down), it prints both from A and B correctly:

```rust
fn main() {
    let _a_runtime = a();
    b();
}

fn a() -> tokio::runtime::Runtime {
    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    runtime.spawn(async { async_task("A".to_string()).await });
    runtime
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn b() {
    tokio::spawn(async move { async_task("B".to_string()).await });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation for the main macro.](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html) There's a clue to why this doesn't work there.

> Note: This macro can be used on any function and not just the main function. Using it on a non-main function makes the function behave as if it was synchronous by starting a new runtime each time it is called. If the function is called often, it is preferable to create the runtime using the runtime builder so the runtime can be reused across calls.

So you can use it on multiple functions, but what that means is that you need to call each one in a separate main function. You could also manually construct it

```rust
fn main() {
    let jh1 = std::thread::spawn(|| a());
    let jh2 = std::thread::spawn(|| b());
    jh1.join().unwrap();
    jh2.join().unwrap();
}

async fn async_task(msg: String) {
    loop {
        tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("I'm awake {}", msg);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn a() {
    async_task("a".to_owned()).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn b() {
    async_task("b".to_owned()).await
}
```